# R Shiny: Can't use function in different tabPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I want to use Shiny to demo my text mining analysis process

But I am confused that shiny can't use finished function(or data, dataframe, matrix...etc) in different tabPanel.

It's really a big trouble for me to build next analysis process.

Is any way to solve this problem?

It shows the error message: 
[image]

here is my test analysis file download link:
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1A9BtTplgy42etAh42YwLiZJAwl_RSNF-

ui.r

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for data upload app ----
navbarPage( 
  title = 'Patent Analysis System',        
  #Table1----------------------------------------------------           
  tabPanel("Upload Patent File", fluidPage(

    # App title ----
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

    # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(
      # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
      sidebarPanel(

        # Input: Select a Patent file ----
        fileInput("patent_file", "Choose Patent File",
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  accept = c("text/csv",
                             "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                             "csv")),

        #submit button
        submitButton("Update View", icon("refresh"))

      ),

      # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
          tabPanel("Load Files",tableOutput("contents"),id="load_files"),

          tabPanel("Patents Preprocess",fluidPage(
            sidebarPanel(
              selectizeInput("choose_patent", "Choose Patent",
                             choices = 1:10 ,selected = 1),
              submitButton("Update", icon("refresh"))
            )
          ),
          verbatimTextOutput("patent_pre_process")),
          tabPanel("Convert martix(TF)", 
                   tableOutput("mat_tf"), id="matrix_tf")
        )
      )
    )
  )),
  tabPanel('Process2 ',  DT::dataTableOutput('ex5'))
)
```

server.r

```
library(ontologyIndex)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr) #separate_rows
library(quanteda) #tolower
library(SnowballC) #wordstem
library(gtools)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(textreg)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30*1024^2)
  #1. File load------------------------------------------------------------------------
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(input$patent_file)
    patent_df <- read.csv(input$patent_file$datapath)
    patent_df

  })

  #2. Patent preprocess----------------------------------------------------------------
  output$patent_pre_process <- renderPrint({
    req(input$patent_file)
    df_cmp <-  read.csv(input$patent_file$datapath, stringsAsFactors = F)

    #Build Corpus (Title)--------------------------------------------------------------
    df_title <- data.frame(Title=df_cmp$English.title)
    corpus_title <- Corpus(DataframeSource(df_title))

    #Pre-processing and tranforming the Corpus
    corpus_tm_title <- tm_map(corpus_title, content_transformer(tolower)) %>%
      tm_map(removeNumbers)

    #Build Corpus (Abstract)------------------------------------------------------------
    df_abstract <- data.frame(abstract=df_cmp$English.abstract)
    corpus_abstract <- Corpus(DataframeSource(df_abstract))

    #Pre-processing and tranforming the Corpus
    corpus_tm_abstract <- tm_map(corpus_abstract, content_transformer(tolower)) %>%
      tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
      tm_map(stripWhitespace)

    #Patent result output---------------------------------------------------------------
    pat_num <- 1:length(df_cmp$Publication.numbers)
    updateSelectInput(session, "choose_patent", "Choose Patent :", choices = pat_num)
    choose_pat_num <- as.integer(input$choose_patent)

    list(Title=content(corpus_tm_title[[choose_pat_num]]),
         Abstract= content(corpus_tm_abstract[[choose_pat_num]]))

  })

  #3. Matix-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  output$mat_tf <- renderTable({

    #Title
    title_convert <- convert.tm.to.character(corpus_tm_title)
    mat_title <- dfm(title_convert, what = "word", remove_punct = FALSE, 
                     ngrams = 1:3, concatenator = " ") %>%
      as.matrix()*3

    #Combine title/ads/claim dtm--------------------------------------------------------
    tf_mat <- cbind(mat_title, mat_abstract) 
    tf_mat
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that you have placed all the computations in render functions. These are design to render output to one single source an nothing else. You really want to put all computatzions like this in reactive expressions and build chains with them. Below I have reformatted your code (with out testing) in a way I think should work well.

```
library(ontologyIndex)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr) #separate_rows
library(quanteda) #tolower
library(SnowballC) #wordstem
library(gtools)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(textreg)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 30*1024^2)
  #1. File load------------------------------------------------------------------------
  patent_df <- reactive({
    read.csv(input$patent_file$datapath, stringsAsFactors = F)
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    req(input$patent_file)
    patent_df()

  })

  #2. Patent preprocess----------------------------------------------------------------
  preProcess <- reactive({
    req(input$patent_file)
    df_cmp <-  patent_df()

    #Build Corpus (Title)--------------------------------------------------------------
    df_title <- data.frame(Title=df_cmp$English.title)
    corpus_title <- Corpus(DataframeSource(df_title))

    #Pre-processing and tranforming the Corpus
    corpus_tm_title <- tm_map(corpus_title, content_transformer(tolower)) %>%
      tm_map(removeNumbers)

    corpus_tm_title
  })

  dtaCorpus <- reactive({
    #Build Corpus (Abstract)------------------------------------------------------------
    df_cmp <-  patent_df()
    corpus_tm_title <- preProcess()
    df_abstract <- data.frame(abstract=df_cmp$English.abstract)
    corpus_abstract <- Corpus(DataframeSource(df_abstract))

    #Pre-processing and tranforming the Corpus
    corpus_tm_abstract <- tm_map(corpus_abstract, content_transformer(tolower)) %>%
      tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
      tm_map(stripWhitespace)

    #Patent result output---------------------------------------------------------------
    pat_num <- 1:length(df_cmp$Publication.numbers)
    updateSelectInput(session, "choose_patent", "Choose Patent :", choices = pat_num)
    choose_pat_num <- as.integer(input$choose_patent)

    list(Title=content(corpus_tm_title[[choose_pat_num]]),
         Abstract= content(corpus_tm_abstract[[choose_pat_num]]))

  })
  output$patent_pre_process <- renderPrint({
    dtaCorpus()
  })

  #3. Matix-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

  output$mat_tf <- renderTable({

    corpus_tm_title <- preProcess()
    #Title
    title_convert <- convert.tm.to.character(corpus_tm_title)
    mat_title <- dfm(title_convert, what = "word", remove_punct = FALSE, 
                     ngrams = 1:3, concatenator = " ") %>%
      as.matrix()*3

    #Combine title/ads/claim dtm--------------------------------------------------------
    tf_mat <- cbind(mat_title, mat_abstract) 
    tf_mat
  })
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I there are any problem with the code I will look closer at it this evening when I have a bit more time

Comment: thanks. I have tried use reactive() for reused object.